# PhpStorm and PHP CS Fixer: shows errors but does not fix

Tags: phpstorm, php-cs-fixer

TIA and this is driving me insane and resources on the web don't appear to be my specific issue.

I have installed PHP CS Fixer globally via Composer:

`php-cs-fixer --version` = `PHP CS Fixer 2.14.2 Sunrise by Fabien Potencier and Darius Ruminski`

Adjusted PHP CS Fixer to run locally and pointed to the .bat file...validation came back fine:
[image: PHP CS Fixer path]

Now when I run my Inspect Code, PHP CS Fixer shows the problems but when I click the lightbulb to fix them...the issues go away from the inspection but the problems are still there in the file itself (re-running it shows the same issues and the file is unchanged).
[image: PHP CS Fixer running]

Nothing is firing in my Event Logs to help diagnose was is/isn't going on :/

Using `PHP CS Fixer 2.14.2` and `PhpStorm 2018.3.4`

Comment: If you use custom .php_cs.dist configuration with specified finder to inspect concrete directories in the project the mentioned problem can be related to the PhpStorm [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-45280) since PHP CS Fixer was started with no working directory specified therefore related paths in custom configuration file were invalid. In this case, the issue should be resolved in PhpStorm EAP 191.5849

Comment: I do not use that and also tried to add it via the link as you said to no avail :(